# What is the type signature of the MUI DatePicker `onChange` event?

Tags: typescript, material-ui, datepicker

I have a [MUI DatePicker](https://mui.com/x/react-date-pickers/date-picker/) with a `MomentAdapter`:

```
import *, {useState} as React from 'react';
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';
import { AdapterMoment } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterMoment';

import { LocalizationProvider } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/LocalizationProvider';
import { DatePicker } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/DatePicker';
import { Moment } from 'moment';

function App() {

  const [value, setValue] = useState<Moment | null>();

  return (
    <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterMoment}>
      <DatePicker
        value={value}
        onChange={(date: Moment | null) => {
          setValue(date);
          console.log(date);
        }}
        renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
      />
    </LocalizationProvider>
  )
}
```

The value of `date` is clearly a `Moment` object, which I can tell my inspecting it in the console:

[image]

But Typescript complains that it expects a `Date` object here.

(To make matters more confusing, I get inconsistent results when I try this forked from the MUI docs on a [StackBlitz](https://react-pe5kx2-3u7xgd.stackblitz.io), where the value does seem to be a date. It's hard to see there because the console doesn't print objects very usefully.)

What should the type signature of `onChange` be here?

Comment: Where is `newValue` defined in your code?

Comment: @caTS edited to fix cut-and-paste typo.

Answer (score 3):

The `onChange` property is defined in the `UsePickerValueBaseProps<TValue, TError>` interface, as:

```
onChange?: (value: TValue, context: PickerChangeHandlerContext<TError>) => void;
```

The `TValue` generic parameter is coming from the `DatePicker` itself, so you can specify it in the component and the `onChange` method will have the correct typing:

```
<DatePicker<Moment> 
  onChange={(date: Moment | null) => {
    setValue(date);
    console.log(date);
  }}
/>
```

You get an error if you don't define it, because `TValue` has a default type of `Date`.

Comment: Looks like this changed from v5 to v6. But AFAICT in order to use the `PickerChangeHandlerContext` type I have to import it from `@mui/x-date-pickers/internals/hooks/usePicker/usePickerValue.types.d.ts`? Yikes.

Comment: Yes indeed, I also had to use this import.

Answer (score 0):

> The value of `date` is clearly a `Moment` object, which I can tell my inspecting it in the console

Consider that you are setting the value to a `Moment` object yourself. Whatever type is used by the component internally may not match the type you are supplying to it. Your `console.log(value)` statement is also checking the type of your `value` variable, and not the new `date` that the component is passing in.

This is what your onChange method should look like, roughly:

```js
onChange={(date: Date | null) => {
          setValue(date);
          console.log(`${date} has type ${typeof date}`);
        }}
```

If you change it to this, see whether this is giving you a `Date` type now.

Comment: Apologies -- I've edited the post to fix a typo with the name of the `onChange` variable. I am actually printing that variable (now called `date`), not the `value` in the state, when I see the Moment object.